# how do I create a widget of my web application

Tags: javascript, web-services, widget

I want to create a small widget of my website. This widget will facilitate easy

- viewing of latest content posted on the website
- embedding it on other website.
- posting of comments instantly to my website from within the widget

How shall I start building such widget.

I heard of this [CROWDSOUND](http://crowdsound.com/), and this is exactly what I want but want to create my own.

Please help me do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the iframe tag in HTML.

This, is, for instance, how Google Gadgets integrates multiple webpages into little boxes in a single home page.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp

http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/

Comment: :)
thanks for giving a start, I thought I would never get an answer to this question. But you proved me wrong.
thank for you help.

Comment: Your welcome.  Actually I find this site to be fairly quick, with lots of feedback.